# How can I get nodetool without Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have Cassandra pool across machines in LAN. I need `nodetool` on machine without Cassandra installed. How can I get it?

Is the installing Cassandra and disabling db service is the best way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest (non-invasive) way is probably to [download the tarball installation](http://planetcassandra.org/cassandra/?action=true) (you'll need to select either a Mac or Linux-based OS for it to allow you to download the tarball).  Based-on your mention of disabling the service, I'm going to guess that you want to accomplish this on Windows.  If that's not the case, please indicate so in the comments.

Un-tar dsc-cassandra-2.0.8-bin.tar.gz to the location you want to run Nodetool out of.  ex:

```
$ cd /tools
$ tar -zxvf dsc-cassandra-2.0.8-bin.tar.gz
```

*Note: You may have a different application you use for tarballs.  I ran this from a [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) terminal.*

Find the location of your JRE/JDK (not the `bin` directory) and [set that as your "JAVA_HOME"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7) (System) environment variable.  When you have it set properly, you should be able to query it via CMD:

```
>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

Once you have JAVA_HOME set, it should work from either CMD or Powershell:

```
C:\tools\dsc-cassandra-2.0.8\bin>nodetool -h 192.168.1.85 status
Starting NodeTool
Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.85  506.29 MB  256     100.0%  cd39f0fe-ed67-40cf-b6bd-504cedabf497  rack1
```

This way, you can run `nodetool` without messing with an installer or services.

Comment: thx for reply! all machines run Debian, but I catch the idea =)

Comment: @dizpers Oh, for Debian it's even easier!  Just untar the file, and make sure Java is installed (and alternatives are properly updated) and it should just "work."